# Javascript DOM tree duplicate for manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

Since the DOM tree of a page is active and always reflected in the browser, what is the best way to modify this DOM tree for some purpose without affecting the actual rendered tree ? Let's say my purpose is to swap certain children nodes and see how similar the DOM tree still remains.

Is creating a duplicate tree the only solution ? If it is, is there a function to do this ? Or do I need to write my own function to create a duplicate copy of the tree. I won't need all the attributes of the element object, so I can create a simpler object with a few attributes that point to the siblings and children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `document.cloneNode(true)`, or the same method on another node.  [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) clones any node, and the `true` means it should be recursive (deep).  Obviously, this could have a significant performance cost on a large page.

Comment: but the new node's childNodes property will still point to the children of the original node. or will the whole subtree be cloned ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use jQuery:

```
var clone = $("selectorForSomeElement(s)").clone();
```

`clone` now is a copy of the element structure.

You can then work off of clone to do whatever experimenting you like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider one the many great JavaScript librarys out there, e.g. jQuery. These allow you to easily copy parts of or even the whole DOM of an document and have that stored appart from the DOM.

If you need to roll your own solution, a good point to start is Resig's post on document fragments: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/.

Good luck.