# Get Default Height Of Element On Webpage after css height has been applied)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I go about getting what the height of an element on a page would be if it ignored the 'height' css property applied to it?

The site I'm working on is http://www.wncba.co.uk/results and the actual script I've got so far is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    document.origContentHeight = $("#auto-resize").outerHeight(true);
    refreshContentSize(); //run initially
    $(window).resize(function() { //run whenever window size changes
        refreshContentSize();
    });
});

function refreshContentSize()
{       
    var startPos = $("#auto-resize").position();
    var topHeight = startPos.top;
    var footerHeight = $("#footer").outerHeight(true);
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();    
    var spaceForContent = viewportHeight - footerHeight - topHeight;

    if (spaceForContent <= document.origContentHeight)
    {
        var newHeight = document.origContentHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        var newHeight = spaceForContent;
    }
    $("#auto-resize").css('height', newHeight);
    return; 
}
```

[ http://www.wncba.co.uk/results/javascript/fill-page.js ]

What I'm trying to do is get the main page content to stretch to fill the window so that the green lines always flow all the way down the page and the 'Valid HTML5' and 'Designed By' messages are never above the bottom of the window. I don't want the footer to stick to the bottom. I just want it to stay there instead of moving up the page if there's not enough content to fill above to fill it. It also must adapt itself accordingly if the browser window size changes.

The script I've got so far works but there's a small issue that I want to fix with it. At the moment if the content on the page changes dynamically (resulting in the page becoming longer or shorter) the script won't detect this. The variable `document.origContentHeight` will remain set as the old height.

Is there a way of detecting the height of an element (e.g. #auto-resize in the example) and whether or not it has changed ignoring the height that has been set for it in css? I would then use this to update the variable `document.origContentHeight` and re-run the script.

Thanks.

Comment: If I cloned the page with the method at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222951/javascript-dom-tree-duplicate-for-manipulation and then removed the extra 'height' property in that and then got the height of that would that work? I presume I'd have to clone it every few seconds to check if it had changed? Would this use a lot of memory? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. I had to rethink it a bit. The solution is on the live site.

The one think I'd like to change if possible is the

```
setInterval('refreshContentSize()', 500); // in case content size changes
```

Is there a way of detecting that the table row has changed size without chacking every 500ms. I tried `(#content).resize(function()` but couldn't to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to detect when an element size changed except using a plugin,

```
$(element).resize(function() //only works when element = window
```

but why don't you call `refreshContentSize` function on page changes dynamically?

Look at this [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26utk/), you will understand what I mean.

Or you can use [Jquery-resize-plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/).

Comment: That is the right idea but the problem is that they way my script works is by automatically adjusting the css height property to make it fit the browser viewport. This means that whenever you try to then get the actual height afterwards it doesn't work because it's been overrided/changed by the css.

Comment: calling the function every time is a good idea but I don't really want to rely on doing this and hard coding it in everytime there's a change.
Plus if there's some content from another site embedded then that could change size and wouldn't know to call the function

Comment: @TomJenkinson, so you should use that Jquery-resize-plugin, [you can bind resize event for any selector you want.](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/docs/files/jquery-ba-resize-js.html#Events)

Comment: I can already do that with the " $(window).resize(function() {" bit in the code. The problem is that I want to detect whether the height of the content IN the #auto-resize container (NOT the actual height of the container as that has been changed to make it fit the page) has changed.

Comment: I think the plugin will tell me if the #auto-resize height changes but it won't because I'm explicitly setting it in the script using the css height property (so it's not telling me the height I want)

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: For example, when you click on a link the loading message comes up and the height of the actual content then if the #auto-resize didn't have a height set would be a lot smaller than it was when it had the page content in. I want the script to then detect this somehow and re-calculate the correct height and update the variable `document.origContentHeight`.

Comment: At the moment if you click a link on [link](http://www.wncba.co.uk/results/?action=navigate&season=2012&league_id=1&nav_key=da43e4af277bc162708618930b5b35b6) the loading box will appear but there's still the scroll bar and all the blank space underneath as the `document.origContentHeight` is wrong. If this was recalculated somehow the script would automatically adjust the #auto-resize height so that the footer text was at the bottom again. Hopefully this explains things a bit clearer!