# Javascript DOM ChildNodes property doesn't capture all children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to save a DOM subtree (everything under the div called "block diagram") then paint it on a div called "bus_diagram". Saving the childNodes property doesn't seem to capture all of the elements for some reason.

here's the javascript I'm using. On calling the function "dostuff()" everything under "block_diagram" should go to "bus_diagram"

```
var SAVED_BLOCK_DOM = null;

function save_block() {
    SAVED_BLOCK_DOM = document.getElementById("block_diagram").childNodes;
}

function refresh_block() {
    for (var i = 0; i < SAVED_BLOCK_DOM.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("bus_diagram").appendChild(SAVED_BLOCK_DOM[i]);
    }
}

function dostuff() {
    save_block();
    refresh_block();
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BFp5s/3/

Comment: check this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222951/javascript-dom-tree-duplicate-for-manipulation

Comment: the `childNode`s is not applied to any of the subsequent children, so that's why every-time you click the button you copy the next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.childNodes` is a live collection of nodes and as you start doing .appendChild() on the nodes (which moves the elements to a different place in the DOM), the live collection changes while you are iterating it, causing you to miss nodes.  So, when the index of your `for` loop is `0`, you do `.appendChild()` on the `0th` element of the list.  That removes that element from the live list.  You then increment your index to `1`, but the next item to process is now in the `0th` spot in the list causing you to process every other item.

You can either make a copy of the live list into an array (so it won't change while iterating it) or change the way you iterate the list.

For example, you can change `save_block()` to this:

```
function save_block() {
    SAVED_BLOCK_DOM = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("block_diagram").childNodes, 0);
}
```

This makes `SAVED_BLOCK_DOM` into a normal array so it won't change while you iterate it.

jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/R8c94/

---

Or, if you want/need to support IE6/7/8 support which won't work with the above copy mechanism, you can just copy the nodeList manually:

```
function save_block() {
    SAVED_BLOCK_DOM = [];
    var list = document.getElementById("block_diagram").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        SAVED_BLOCK_DOM.push(list[i]);
    }
}
```

---

If you don't need `SAVED_BLOCK_DOM` to continue to hold the list of nodes and want to support IE8, you can change the way you iterate like this:

```
function refresh_block() {
    while (SAVED_BLOCK_DOM.length) {
        document.getElementById("bus_diagram").appendChild(SAVED_BLOCK_DOM[0]);
    }
}
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PK7Tg/

Comment: Passing a host object to *slice* will fail in IE8 :-( so better to do a normal loop, or use *querySelectorAll*, which works in IE8 and returns a static NodeList. :-)

Comment: @RobG - if you want to support IE8.  Also, you can't necessarily get the equivalent of `.childNodes` with `querySelectorAll()` if there are text nodes in there so you would have to do it differently.

Comment: If you believe [*NetMarketShare*](http://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), IE 8 (or browsers that identify as IE 8) is 20% of the desktop browser market. I visited a site recently with IE 9 and was refused entry because they don't support IE 8.

Comment: @RobG - let's not go off in a tangent here - I've added an alternate way of doing it.

Comment: @RobG's comments were a useful contribution to your original solution. You shouldn't be so dismissive and defensive when potential issues are pointed out.